# Geocoder giving different results depending on API key

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

I am trying to retrieve coordinates for a specific address using Google geocoding service. Here is the HTTP request:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=EPIM%20Aix-En-Provence,%20Luynes,%20France&key=MY_DEV_KEY`

The thing is that using my free development key (or with no key at all, it is the same), I get the result I expect:

*"EPIM Aix-En-Provence, 18 Quartier Plein Soleil - 600 Route de Marseille, 13080 Luynes, France"*

But when I switch to production and change the key to my production key, then I get a different (and completely wrong) result (*"37230 Luynes, France"*).

I even tried with a simple curl call to avoid any header added by the browser, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: perhaps you could experiment with the `new_forward_geocoder` flag, that might be what is making the difference.  See [Address Geocoding in the Google Maps APIs:Future Changes to Geocoding API](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/11/address-geocoding-in-google-maps-apis.html) for more details.

Comment: @geocodezip: you made my day ! If you want to post the comment as the answer, I'll be glad to approve it. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Posted answer, glad the comment helped.

Comment: But that still didn't help me. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Address Geocoding in the Google Maps APIs:Future Changes to Geocoding API](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/11/address-geocoding-in-google-maps-apis.html), there is a change to the Geocoder which is in the process of being implemented which may cause the geocoder to depend on the presence of an API key.

You can experiment with the `new_forward_geocoder` flag in the request to verify if this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If, when switching to production, someone still has the same issue after having placed the **new_forward_geocoder=true** before the key, try to place it also after, that is (in my case it worked for me) src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?new_forward_geocoder=true&key=MY_DEV_KEY&new_forward_geocoder=true"